# backpack laravel - preselect select filter with $_GET param

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a Document and Post (for that document) Backpack CRUD resources. I want to create a button inside the post datatable so that when I click that button, it will link to the documents of that post.

this is my model post

```
class Post extends Model{
    ...
    function allDocuments(){
        return '<a href="/admin/document/?post_id='.$this->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Documents</a>';
    }
}
```

this is my `PostCrudController`

```
class PostCrudController extends CrudController{
    ...
    $this->crud->addButtonFromModelFunction('line', 'all_documents', 'allDocuments', 'beginning');

}
```

and that's my `DocumentCrudController`

```
class DocumentCrudController extends CrudController{
    ...
            $this->crud->addFilter([ 
              'name' => 'post_id',
              'type' => 'select2',
              'label'=> 'Post To Filter',
              'value' => $_GET['post_id'] // <------- Hoped this works, but doesn't
            ], function() {
                $condos = [];
                foreach(Post::get() as $c){
                    $condos[$c->id] = $c->title." >> ".$c->category->name." >> ".$c->category->condomimium->name;
                }
                return $condos;
            }, function($value) { // if the filter is active
                $this->crud->addClause('where', 'post_id', $value);
            });
}
```

I've seen that backpack datatables uses a POST request with the parameters (in my case `post_id`) to filter the datatable, but I need to call a GET request to preselect my filter with the datatable result accordingly.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET`

Comment: Why not using Request in laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Request in laravel ? something like this `$request->input(post_id);` and instantiate the request in the method like this

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function store(Request $request) { // logic here }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works even without `'value' => $_GET['post_id']`. Backpack recognizes automatically filter. The name of the filter must match to the name of the `GET` param

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get something similar working and any improvement is much appreciated..

i needed to make a column that link to the child model and and show only the linked items in the table therefore i wrote this in a trait

protected function redirect_filter_column($_name, $_attribute, $_query){ $this->crud->addColumn([ 'name' => $*name, 'label' => ucwords(Str::replace('*', ' ', $_name)), 'type' => 'select', 'attribute' => $_attribute, 'entity' => $_name, 'wrapper' => [ 'element' => 'a', 'href' => function ($crud, $column, $entry, $related_key) use ($_query){ return backpack_url( $column['entity'] . '?' . $_query . '=' .$related_key . '&id' . '=' . $related_key ); }, ] ]);

In the crud controller for the related (belongs to) model i used this to filter
`
$query = $this->crud->query;

```
if (request()->get('parent_id')) {
    $query->orWhere('parent_id', request()->get('parent_id'));
}
if (request()->get('id')){
    $query->orWhere('id', request()->get('id'));
}

$this->crud->query = $query;
```

`

it worked for me